# ¿Cómo puedo enviar correos desde mi aplicación en xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
          <StackLayout>
                <Label
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Margin="30"
                    Text="Send a message to a teacher"/>
                <Entry
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Placeholder="Enter your name"
                    PlaceholderColor="White"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Entry
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Placeholder="Enter your email"
                    PlaceholderColor="White"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Entry
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Placeholder="Enter the name of the teacher"
                    PlaceholderColor="White"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Entry
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Placeholder="Enter the tilte of the message"
                    PlaceholderColor="White"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Editor
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Placeholder="Enter your message"
                    PlaceholderColor="White"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Button
                    WidthRequest="250"
                    Text="Send"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    Margin="20"
                    BorderRadius="20"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

Estoy trabajando con xamarin cross-platfom y he creado un formulario, pero como hago que cuando el usuario ingrese todo y de click en enviar, envien un correo. No importa si debo pasar por gmail (prefiero no pasar por ahí). Se pueden enviar directamente desde mi app? Solamente he hecho el diseño del formulario.

Comment: Con Xamarin Essentials puedes enviar correos desde tu App, aquí te dejo el link:\
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/email?tabs=ios